# Jquery: How can I Get/Set html of a String Variable by using Jquery Selectors?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Firstly, sorry for my English (I'm from China).

By reading this article([[how to apply jQuery element selection to a string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421719/how-to-apply-jquery-element-selection-to-a-string-variable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421719/how-to-apply-jquery-element-selection-to-a-string-variable)), I can successfully get Elements from a String which stores HTML text. For example:

```
var htmlstr = "<div><ul><li>some text 1</li></ul></div><div><ul id=list><li>some text 2</li></ul></div>";
var s = $('ul#list', $(htmlstr)).html();
```

`s` will be `<li>some text 2</li>`. It's what I want.

But the question is, if I want to add another LI element to this string (htmlstr) how can I do?

I set `s` = new html string but `htmlstr` doesn't change.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this in a bit less code:

```
var htmlstr = "<div><ul><li>some text 1</li></ul></div><div><ul id='list'><li>some text 2</li></ul></div>";
htmlstr = $("<div />").html(htmlstr).find("ul#list").append("<li>New Item</li>").end().html();
alert(htmlstr);
```

Just change that find selector and/or the append text if you want to stick the element in a different place.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible to select the ul and append the new li, with the following method: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best way but what about this:

```
var htmlstr = "<div><ul><li>some text 1</li></ul></div><div><ul id=list><li>some text 2</li></ul></div>";
// make sure you choose a suitable Id here that won't conflict
$('body').append('<div id="test" style="display: none;">' + htmlstr + '</div>');

$test = $('#test');

$test.find('ul').append('<li>new</li>');

htmlstr = $test.html();
// clean up the DOM
$test.remove();


var s = $('ul#list', $(htmlstr)).html();
```

Basically, you insert the HTML into the DOM, append the new list item and then get the resulting HTML back and remove the elements you added.

Comment: good idea! I will use this one if I can't find any solution better

:) thanks~